# What is the probability of having similar summation values

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation

Given a vector of non-increasing positive integers $A=[a_1, \cdots, a_n]$, where $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n}{a_i}=n(n-1)$, what is the probability that a random non-increasing vector $B=[b_1, \cdots, b_n]$, where $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n}{b_i}=n(n-1)$, has the following property $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n}{i \cdot a_i} = \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n}{i \cdot b_i}$?

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the distribution of $B$. However with a wide range of distributions it is almost certain (having zero probability) that $B$ does not have those properties. The sums will require $B$ to lie in an affine space  of dimension $n-2$ which normally is a set of zero measure in $\mathbb R^n$. Even the prerequisite that $B$ is non-increasing should not alter this.

Otherwise there do exist such vectors. Take for example:

$$b_j = \begin{cases}
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k & \text{if }  j = 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: The condition is $\sum_{i} i \times b_i = \sum_{i} i \times a_i$, not just the sums of $a_i$ and $b_i$ must be equal.

Comment: I phrased my question in the wrong way. I meant what is the probability of finding such vector $B$. Furthermore, as pointed out by @Hetebrij, the condition is different with yours.

Comment: @emab I've updated the answer to reflect your changed question. Also note that probability of finding such vector and probability that a random vector is such is not the same thing (compare the probability of finding a six on a dice and actually getting a six when throwing the dice).